# Why does building a set fail when using set(int)?

Tags: python, set, iterable

I can do

```
>>> s = {1}
>>> type(s)
<class 'set'>
```

but

```
>>> s = set(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

What is the difference?

Comment: Normal, you will see the same with `[1]` and `list(1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that the `set()` constructor takes an iterable. A single number is not an iterable.

```
s = set((1,))
```